# struts2-jquery autocomplete not accepting string that which not belongs to its list

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

```
<s:form action="EmpAction">
<sj:autocompleter label="User Name (or) Login Name" name="loginName" autoComplete="true" list="userNameList"  />
<s:submit />
</s:form>
```

In this when I type a user name that which is from the list `userNameList`, and hit SUBMIT. I get the value in the Struts2 Action class. But when I type a user name that which is not in the `userNameList` and hit SUBMIT, I get only empty string. What do I need to do when to get this string into my Action class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default autocompleter from struts2-jquery plugin forces selection to be one of the options. To change this you need to set `forceValidOption` attribute to `false` in `<sj:autocompleter>` tag.

Comment: this is not helping me

Comment: If this is not helping you then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: This is my code , Whats wrong here - 

<sj:autocompleter id="cityId"          name="mission.cityName" list="cityList" selectBox="true" autoComplete="true" forceValidOption="false" />